# Transcrevendo de MySQL para SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Como fica esse código de MySQL em SQL (no Dbeaver com conexão com Azure)?

**Eu só preciso alterar o SELECT pra funcionar no SQL**

**CRIAÇÃO DAS TABELAS**

**-- TABELA VAGAS**

```
create table vagas (

idSensor int primary key,

idVagas varchar(5),

fkSetor int,

foreign key(fkSetor) references setor(idSetor),

descVagas varchar(20)
)auto_increment = 10;
```

**-- TABELA DE MOVIMENTO**

```
create table  movimento (

idMovimento int primary key auto_increment,

movimentacao int, -- Alterei aqui pra por como int pq binary não tava rodando, não sei porquê

dataHora datetime,

estadia varchar(20),

fkSensor int, -- foreign key
foreign key (fkSensor) references vagas (idSensor)
);
```

**-- INSERINDO DADOS NA TABELA**

**-- TABELA VAGAS**

```
insert into vagas values

(10,'A1',1, 'Coberta'),

(11,'A2',1, 'Descobertas'),

(12,'A3',1, 'PcD'),

(13,'A4',1, 'Idosos'),

(14,'B1',2, 'Coberta'),

(15,'B2',2, 'PcD'),

(16,'B3',2, 'Descobertas'),

(17,'B4',2, 'Coberta'),

(18,'G1',3, 'Descobertas'),

(19,'G2',3, 'Idosos'),

(20,'G3',3, 'PcD'),

(21,'G4',3, 'Coberta'),

(22,'F1',4, 'Idosos'),

(23,'F2',4, 'Coberta'),

(24,'F3',4, 'PcD'),

(25,'F4',4, 'Coberta'),

(26,'A5', 1, 'Idosos'), 

(27,'E1', 4, 'Idosos'),

(28,'E2', 4, 'Idosos');
```

**-- TABELA MOVIMENTO**

```
insert into movimento values

                            (null,1,'2020-05-02 15:03:00','15 min',24), 

                            (null,0,'2020-05-02 15:18:00','15 min',24),

                            (null,1,'2020-06-17 13:00:00','1 Hr+',11), 

                            (null,0,'2020-06-17 14:00:00','1 Hr+',11),

                            (null,1,'2020-06-17 14:10:00','45 min',11), 

                            (null,0,'2020-06-17 14:55:00','45 min',11),

                            (null,1,'2020-06-17 15:43:00','30 min',15),

                            (null,0,'2020-06-17 16:13:00','30 min',15),

                            (null,0,'2020-06-17 12:14:00','1 Hr+',13),

                            (null,1,'2020-06-17 19:43:00','1 Hr+',13), 

                            (null,1,'2020-05-02 07:03:00','15 min',12),

                            (null,0,'2020-05-02 17:18:00','15 min',12),   
 
                            (null,1,'2020-05-02 02:03:00','15 min',13), 

                            (null,0,'2020-05-02 02:18:00','15 min',13),

                            (null,1,'2020-05-02 19:03:00','15 min',12), 

                            (null,0,'2020-05-02 19:18:00','15 min',12),

                            (null,1,'2020-05-02 19:03:00','15 min',14),

                            (null,0,'2020-05-02 19:18:00','15 min',14);
```

**-- ESSE SELECT AQUI Q NÃO RODA NO SQL**

```
SET @total = (SELECT COUNT(estadia) FROM movimento where movimentacao = 1);

SET @totalGeral = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT(@total)) from movimento where movimentacao = 1);   

SELECT -- Total aqui tem 10

CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SUM(IF(TIME(dataHora) between '06:00:00' and '11:59:59', 1,0 ) and movimentacao = 1)/ @totalGeral) * 100),0),'%') as 'Manhã',

CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SUM(IF(TIME(dataHora) between '12:00:00' and '18:59:59', 1,0 )and movimentacao = 1)/ @totalGeral) * 100),0),'%') as 'Tarde',

CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SUM(IF(TIME(dataHora) between '19:00:00' and '23:59:59', 1,0 )and movimentacao = 1)/ @totalGeral) * 100),0),'%') as 'Noite',

CONCAT(TRUNCATE(((SUM(IF(TIME(dataHora) between '00:00:00' and '05:59:59', 1,0 )and movimentacao = 1)/ @totalGeral) * 100),0),'%') as 'Madrugada'
FROM movimento;
```

Comment: Mas o que o seu código faz? É legal pelo menos dar um resumo para que o pessoal possa te dar sugestões.

Comment: Então, é um sistema de estacionamento
Esse código conta quantas entradas tiveram em X período e classifica elas por manhã, tarde,noite ou madrugada
Só que esse valor é mostrado em porcentagem

Comment: Consegue colocar a estrutura das tabelas (`CREATE TABLE`) e alguns dados para que possamos testar diferentes `queries` e sugerir soluções?

Comment: Apaguei daqui e editei direto na questão! Acho que fica mais organizado! Desculpa a pergunta inicialmente ter ficado mto vaga, é a minha primeira vez aqui e não sabia exatamente como deveria perguntar e ser bem clara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente basta que você use a função `DATEPART` para verificar qual a hora do seu `DATETIME` e assim categorizar de acordo com o que quer. Fiz um exemplo mais simplificado abaixo porque não entendi o seu intuito com a variável `totalGeral` e com a coluna `movimentacao`.

```
DECLARE @total INT;

SELECT @total = COUNT(1)
  FROM movimento m;

WITH periodo AS (
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, m.dataHora) BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN 0 -- Manhã
           WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, m.dataHora) BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN 1 -- Tarde
           WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, m.dataHora) BETWEEN 17 AND 23 THEN 2 -- Noite
           ELSE 3 -- Madrugada
         END AS periodo
    FROM movimento m
),
total AS (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.periodo = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS manha,
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.periodo = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tarde,
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.periodo = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS noite,
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.periodo = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS madrugada
    FROM periodo p
)
SELECT CAST((t.manha / @total) * 100 AS VARCHAR) + '%' as 'Manhã',
       CAST((t.tarde / @total) * 100 AS VARCHAR) + '%' as 'Tarde',
       CAST((t.noite / @total) * 100 AS VARCHAR) + '%' as 'Noite',
       CAST((t.madrugada / @total) * 100 AS VARCHAR) + '%' as 'Madrugada'
  FROM total t
```

Comment: Ah a totalGeral e a total eram só pra me ajudar a transformar o cálculo numa porcentagem já que não sabia exatamente como fazer!
A movimentacao é uma coluna que indica se a  vaga está ocupada (1) ou desocupada (0) coloquei que so contava quando fosse 1 pq só quero contar as entradas!

Eu testei aqui e por algum motivo ele me retorna todos em 0%, alterei pra contar somente quando forem encontradas (1/entradas) na movimentacao e agr ele me retorna todos como 0% e somente a tarde como 100% :(

Comment: Consegui ajeitar aqui! Mas fiquei com uma dúvida, ele só faz a conta 
ali no CAST 

'CAST((t.manha / @total) * 100 AS VARCHAR) + '%' as 'Manhã',

'se o @total estiver  declarado lá em cima como float (não consegui de jeito nenhum fazer a conta com o valor declarado como inteiro) O que poderia ser isso?

Comment: @BeatrizBarbosa cai em erro de conversão, você não pode concatenar um `VARCHAR` com um numérico. Se a resposta lhe atendeu não esqueça de marcá-la como correta clicando no V do lado esquerdo da resposta.